# AttributeError for function called in another function within same class - Python

Tags: python

When I run the following code I get an AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute findMean. What am I doing wrong?

```
class BasicStats:    

    def findMean(self, num = {}):
        length = len(num)

        sum = 0
        for x in num:
            sum = sum + x

        mean =sum/length
        return mean     

    def findVariance(self, num = {}):
        mean = self.findMean(num)
        length = len(num)

        squared_difference = 0
        for x in num:
            squared_difference = squared_difference + (x-mean)**2

        variance = squared_difference/length
        return variance

    arr = {1, 23, 343.34, 2}    
    findVariance(arr)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `self` in that scope is a `set`. More specifically, it is `arr` (which is a set and you pass in as the first argument).

The `self` keyword only works for functions called against an instance of a class (this special type of functions are called methods, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086830/python-calling-method-in-class).)

Comment: Thanks for the help. What do I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: You should try something like the following **outside the class**: `stats = BasicStats()` and then `print(stats.findMean(arr))`