# I Have two different errors within my code one being with the class and one to do with the login function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "H:\PythonGroupWork\Python Code\tests\login.py", line 4, in 
    class tits():

File "H:\PythonGroupWork\Python Code\tests\login.py", line 97, in tits
    Login()

TypeError: Login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

```
from tkinter import *
import os

class login:

    creds = 'H:\\PythonGroupWork\\Logins\\users.txt'# This just sets the variable creds to 'tempfile.temp'

    def Signup(self): # This is the signup definition,
        global pwordE # These globals just make the variables global to the entire script, meaning any definition can use them
        global nameE
        global roots

        roots = Tk() # This creates the window, just a blank one.
        roots.title('Signup') # This renames the title of said window to 'signup'
        intruction = Label(roots, text='Please Enter new Credidentials\n') # This puts a label, so just a piece of text saying 'please enter blah'
        intruction.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E) # This just puts it in the window, on row 0, col 0. If you want to learn more look up a tkinter tutorial :)

        nameL = Label(roots, text='New Username: ') # This just does the same as above, instead with the text new username.
        pwordL = Label(roots, text='New Password: ') # ^^
        nameL.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W) # Same thing as the instruction var just on different rows. :) Tkinter is like that.
        pwordL.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W) # ^^

        nameE = Entry(roots) # This now puts a text box waiting for input.
        pwordE = Entry(roots, show='*') # Same as above, yet 'show="*"' What this does is replace the text with *, like a password box :D
        nameE.grid(row=1, column=1) # You know what this does now :D
        pwordE.grid(row=2, column=1) # ^^

        signupButton = Button(roots, text='Signup', command=FSSignup) # This creates the button with the text 'signup', when you click it, the command 'fssignup' will run. which is the def
        signupButton.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)
        roots.mainloop() # This just makes the window keep open, we will destroy it soon

    def FSSignup(self):
        with open(creds, 'w') as f: # Creates a document using the variable we made at the top.
            f.write(nameE.get()) # nameE is the variable we were storing the input to. Tkinter makes us use .get() to get the actual string.
            f.write('\n') # Splits the line so both variables are on different lines.
            f.write(pwordE.get()) # Same as nameE just with pword var
            f.close() # Closes the file

        roots.destroy() # This will destroy the signup window. :)
        Login() # This will move us onto the login definition :D

    def Login(self):
        global nameEL
        global pwordEL # More globals :D
        global rootA

        rootA = Tk() # This now makes a new window.
        rootA.title('Login') # This makes the window title 'login'

        intruction = Label(rootA, text='Please Login\n') # More labels to tell us what they do
        intruction.grid(sticky=E) # Blahdy Blah

        nameL = Label(rootA, text='Username: ') # More labels
        pwordL = Label(rootA, text='Password: ') # ^
        nameL.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
        pwordL.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

        nameEL = Entry(rootA) # The entry input
        pwordEL = Entry(rootA, show='*')
        nameEL.grid(row=1, column=1)
        pwordEL.grid(row=2, column=1)

        loginB = Button(rootA, text='Login', command=CheckLogin) # This makes the login button, which will go to the CheckLogin def.
        loginB.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

        rmuser = Button(rootA, text='Delete User', fg='red', command=DelUser) # This makes the deluser button. blah go to the deluser def.
        rmuser.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)
        rootA.mainloop()

    def CheckLogin(self):
        with open(creds) as f:
            data = f.readlines() # This takes the entire document we put the info into and puts it into the data variable
            uname = data[0].rstrip() # Data[0], 0 is the first line, 1 is the second and so on.
            pword = data[1].rstrip() # Using .rstrip() will remove the \n (new line) word from before when we input it

        if nameEL.get() == uname and pwordEL.get() == pword: # Checks to see if you entered the correct data.
            r = Tk() # Opens new window
            r.title(':D')
            r.geometry('150x50') # Makes the window a certain size
            rlbl = Label(r, text='\n[+] Logged In') # "logged in" label
            rlbl.pack() # Pack is like .grid(), just different
            r.mainloop()
        else:
            r = Tk()
            r.title('D:')
            r.geometry('150x50')
            rlbl = Label(r, text='\n[!] Invalid Login')
            rlbl.pack()
            r.mainloop()

    def DelUser(self):
        os.remove(creds) # Removes the file
        rootA.destroy() # Destroys the login window
        Signup() # And goes back to the start!

    if os.path.isfile(creds):
        Login()
    else: # This if else statement checks to see if the file exists. If it does it will go to Login, if not it will go to Signup :)
        Signup()
```

Comment: `self` isn't passed to the functions, change to `Login()` and `Signup()`...also the indentation seems to be off

Comment: ok ive done that but now it gives me a new error. check my edit for the details

Comment: fix your indentation...if you want to call those functions they are part of the class `login` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14086857/3462319 for an example on how to call methods from a class

Comment: as far as i can tell i am sure there arent any indentation problems.

Comment: as it is posted `if os.path.isfile(creds):` doesn't seem to belong to any method correct?

Comment: no its not. it is its own function that would check if there is any text within my file and if there is it would the bring me to the login stage and if not it will bring me to the sign-up stage

Comment: what method is it part of?

Comment: its not part of any method. it is its own function

Comment: which one? right now it has the same indentation as the methods in `login`

Comment: honestly i am not sure, but when you take this out of a class and take all the 'self' out then it works fine. but i need it in a class and thats what i didn't realise until after making this

Comment: why don't you add it to a method `def start(self)` or something similar?

Comment: ok. ive done that and now my gui doesnt even open at all.

Comment: do you call start()?

Comment: yes i did and this is the error i get

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    start()
NameError: name 'start' is not defined