# Python: call to self function not working correctly

Tags: python, django, self

This seems like a very simple issue, and though I have a workaround I would like to fix it nicely.

EDIT: I am using a Django system, so the `groups` variable is actually inherited/retrieved from a DB) I just tried to make a minimal example, but I realised that that was not conducive to solving my issue

I have a class:

```
class Invite(models.Model, IndexedModelMixin):

    def get_associated_groups(self):
        return self.groups
```

But when I call `get_associated_groups` elsewhere

```
def get_groups(resource_object):
    resource_group_objects = resource_object.get_associated_groups()
```

where `Invite` is the `resource_object`, this error is thrown:

`get_associated_groups() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

My workaround currently is

```
resource_group_objects = resource_object.get_associated_groups(resource_object)
```

Why isn't the self call implicit?

Comment: `def __init__(self): self.groups = ...` https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

Comment: @DeepSpace I edited the question, though maybe it's still the same issue? I can't really use `__init__` with Django

Comment: It is most likely that `resource_object` is not an instance of `Invite` but a reference to the `Invite` class itself. Please do `print(type(resource_object))` and verify the way you instantiate `resource_object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where Invite is the resource_object, this error is thrown:

Here **`Invite`** is the ***class***, it should be the ***class instance***.
 That is, You should pass the "instance of the **`Ivaite`** model/class" instead of the **`Invite`** class

```
invite_instance = Invite.objects.get(id=1)
get_groups(invite_instance) # calling the function
```

---

**Reference**
1. [Python calling method in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086830/python-calling-method-in-class)

---

### Example

```
In [3]: class Foo: 
   ...:     names = ["Tony", "George"] 
   ...:  
   ...:     def get_names(self): 
   ...:         return self.names 
   ...:  
   ...:  
   ...: def retrieve_names(foo_instance): 
   ...:     return foo_instance.get_names()                                                                                                                                                                        

In [4]:                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [4]: retrieve_names(Foo)                                                                                                                                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-3eb7dbe1c600> in <module>
----> 1 retrieve_names(Foo)

<ipython-input-3-dbb19979fd85> in retrieve_names(foo_instance)
      7 
      8 def retrieve_names(foo_instance):
----> 9     return foo_instance.get_names()

TypeError: get_names() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

In [5]:                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [5]: foo_inst = Foo()                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [6]: retrieve_names(foo_inst)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[6]: ['Tony', 'George']
```