# Populate Python Pandas Dataframe with Target Variable Column from Correlation Matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class, correlation

I have a pandas dataframe of 45 variables of varying data types and I am using 'dython.nominal' package to create a matrix of associations between each of those variables.

I then want to:

A: subset my dataframe (filter by geographical location) and compute an association matrix on that subset, then

B: create and add to second pandas dataframe with the columns of a target variable from the dataframe created in step A.

The resulting dataframe will then be a matrix of correlations with column indices being georgraphical location and row indices being the other 44 variables.

The code I have so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
from dython.nominal import  compute_associations

temp_df = pd.DataFrame
for item in postcode_partials:
    temp_data = all_data[all_data['Post Code'].str.contains(item)]
    temp_matrix = compute_associations(temp_data, nominal_columns='auto', mark_columns=True, theil_u=True)
    temp_df[item] = temp_matrix['Last Balance (con)'].values
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
'type' object does not support item assignment
```

I'm quite new to pandas as I haven't had much experience of using them in practice. Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks
Andy

Comment: what's there in `postcode_partials`? also, Initialization should be `temp_df = pd.DataFrame()`, a call.

Comment: Hi there. It is a python list of string values (segment of postcode indicating geographical location). It looks like you have answered my question anyway. The problem looks to have been that I didn't include the brackeds after 'Dataframe'. Schoolboy error. :) Thank you for your help, Andy

Comment: Nice. Glad to have helped @furbaw

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct way to create a new instance of the class [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). Instead of `temp_df = pd.DataFrame`, for one to create a new instance of that class and assign the object to the local variable `temp_df` do the following

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

It works this way, because

> Class instantiation uses function notation. Just pretend that the
> class object is a parameterless function that returns a new instance
> of the class. [[Source](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)]

Additional relevant links:

- [Python calling method in class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14086830/7109869), SO Q&A.
- [Python's Instance, Class, and Static Methods Demystified](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/), from RealPython.