# Calling a Function Inside of a Function Inside of a Class | Python & SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to insert data from a .txt file to a SQLite database but whenever I run my code I get this error: `NameError: name 'get_value' is not defined`. Is this because im trying to call a function in a function inside of a class? I didn't include the other parts of my code because I didn't think they are needed but if they are let me know and I'll add it.

Python File:

```
class InputFromIPLog:
    
    ...

    def get_value():
        info = item.strip().split(':')
        val = info[1].strip().split(',')
        return val[0].strip()

    def insert_data():
        with open(f"new_iplog.txt", "r") as f:
            file_data = f.readlines()

        input_gamertag = ""
        input_ip_address = ""
        input_xuid = ""
        input_mid = ""

        for item in file_data:
            if "Gamertag" in item:
                input_gamertag = get_value(item)
            elif "IP Address" in item:
                input_ip_address = get_value(item)
            elif 'XUID' in item:
                input_xuid = get_value(item)
            elif 'MID' in item:
                input_mid = get_value(item)

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO userinfo (gamertag, ip, xuid, mid) values(?, ?, ?)", (input_gamertag, input_ip_address, input_xuid, input_mid,))

...
```

new_iplog.txt File:

```
...

Gamertag: UnknownUser                       
IP Address: 10.0.0.1
XUID: 000301F23B9F6ED4
MID: FB00FDA037CEB46E

Gamertag: AnotherUnknownUser                   
IP Address: 1.1.1.1
XUID: 0009000005E96E9B
MID: FB00F5413910FEDD

...
```

Comment: I can't find a dupe, but one surely exists so I won't post an answer. You need `self.get_value` though to refer to the method. Methods names aren't in a scope on their own. You need to explicitly call the method on an instance of the class (`self` in this case).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086830/python-calling-method-in-class) is a dupe that explains it, but it's a terrible dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you have other attributes tied to the instance of this class, but generally to access methods and attributes of a class you should be using `self`.

Here's a [Intro to Designing Classes](https://dfrieds.com/python/design-classes.html) page which goes over self and how it is used.

With my limited view of your problem, something like below might work:

```py
class InputFromIPLog:
    ...

    def get_value(self, item):
        info = item.strip().split(':')
        val = info[1].strip().split(',')
        return val[0].strip()

    def insert_data(self):
        with open(f"new_iplog.txt", "r") as f:
            file_data = f.readlines()

        input_gamertag = ""
        input_ip_address = ""
        input_xuid = ""
        input_mid = ""

        for item in file_data:
            if "Gamertag" in item:
                input_gamertag = self.get_value(item)
            elif "IP Address" in item:
                input_ip_address = self.get_value(item)
            elif 'XUID' in item:
                input_xuid = self.get_value(item)
            elif 'MID' in item:
                input_mid = self.get_value(item)

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO userinfo (gamertag, ip, xuid, mid) values(?, ?, ?)",
                       (input_gamertag, input_ip_address, input_xuid, input_mid,))


...
```

Also, in your code, `get_value` takes no parameters, but when you use it you pass `item` to it. I've updated the arguments of the function in the code above to reflect your usage.